# Pull out significant variables from stepwise variable process and include in data table

Tags: r, variables, selection

I need to find the significant variables from step-wise (both direction) variable selection process and include in data table for data extraction.

```
iris$area <- iris$Petal.Length * iris$Petal.Width
iris <- data.table(iris)
mydata <- iris[Species %in% "virginica", list(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width,area)]

fit <- lm(area~., data=mydata)
satis.step <- step(fit, direction="both")

datanew <- iris[Species %in% "virginica", list(Species, satis.step)]

    Output:
(Let's assume step wise regression selects Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width so it has the values for the those two predictors)

 datanew <- iris[Species %in% "virginica", list(Species, Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)]
```

I am having difficulty in setting this up in R envrionment.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
datanew <- data[union(c(YEAR, RANGE, ID, COUNTY, LR),
                      attr(satis.step$formula, "term.labels"))]
```

Working example:

```
m1 = lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
m2 = step(m1)
attr(m2$formula, "term.labels")
# [1] "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

The `union` should take care of any duplicates.

Comment: Don't know whether my question was clear. I have revised the last line in the above code. I want to identify the variables from the list of (Precip, Min Temp, Max Temp, Sunshine, Humidity, PET) based on the step-wise variable selection process and to include ONLY the identified significant variables (satis.step) into the list to extract values from "table1".   
datanew <- table1[YEAR %in% years, list(YEAR, RANGE, ID, COUNTY, LR, satis.step)]

Comment: I believe that is what my code does. If you are still having issues, please post a reproducible example so we have the same inputs to work with.

Comment: Please see the revised code above with a reproducible example code. I want the values to list the predictors selected in the step wise regression process in the "datanew". Hope I made this clear.